# How to use jQuery to submit a form and specify which submit button to use

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose a form has multiple submit buttons:

```html
...
<button type="submit" value="deletefoo">Delete Foo</button>
<button type="submit" value="deletebar">Delete Bar</button>
<button type="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button>
...
```

I am intercepting the clicks for only the 2 delete buttons and disabling the form submit to trigger a custom modal dialog which has OK and CANCEL buttons on it to confirm user choice. If user presses OK, I want to submit the form.  If cancel, then dialog dismissed and nothing happens.

I have the first part wired up to trigger the dialog but I am at a loss on how to get the OK button in the dialog to trigger the form submit contingent on which original submit button was pressed (e.g. if `Delete` button pressed, I want to confirm with user they want to delete, then if so, submit the form as normal.

I've searched around and look at jQuery docs but haven't found the answer yet so I must be missing something really straightforward.

**Update:** I don't want to use JS confirm function. In my original question above I'm looking to use a custom modal dialog for various reasons.

Comment: Updated original question to specifically call out again that I'm using a custom modal jquery dialog, not JS Confirm.

Comment: Also updated to add example where there are 3 buttons and I'm only intercepting 2 delete actions. Some answers are proposing intercepting all submit buttons which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the JS confirm function and put it as an onclick event.

You have a nice example [here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php).

Comment: I'm using my own custom modal dialogs, so want to show those vs. using JS confirm function.

Comment: The principle is the same, add different onclick events to the both buttons. To submit the form, use [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function.

Comment: I'm not following. If I just use the .submit function, which submit button action will be invoked? Remember there are 2 or more submit buttons for the form.

Comment: Right, sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant to use the submit button for the default submit function but the main idea is in the onclick events. I'm not sure how you implemented each button so I can't give you more accurate ideas, but that's where you should start.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have them be regular buttons and then onclick set a variable to determine the action type and then when the form submits include this hidden variable and check that to find what you're supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd have to intercept both (all) the buttons, you could do this easily by fetching any of the submit buttons within a specific form, then you can ask your question and given you still have the current event handler, you can figure out what button was pressed and do the callback you'd like. For example:

```
 <form id="myform">
   <button type="submit" value="delete">Delete</button>
   <button type="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

--

```
$(function() {
  $("form#myform button[type='submit']").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("you sure")) {
        var action = $(ev.currentTarget).val();
        console.log(action);    
    }

   });
});
```

JSLint is here: http://jsfiddle.net/r48Cb/

Basically, `console.log(action)` will output either "delete" or "Edit" based on the original click. How you handle that value is up to you. A switch statement, a simple if block could work, but it's up to you, I don't know the scope of your app.

Comment: In my original question, I state that I want to use my own custom modal dialog, so using the JS confirm isn't the approach I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't have to use that confirm. You can use whatever you want there, but this solution solves your problem of figuring out the original intent.

Answer (score 0):

The window.confirm function returns a true if the user selects okay and a false if the user cancels. Using this logic you could do something like this:

```
<button id="delete" type="submit" value="delete">Delete</button>
<button type="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button>

var question;
$("#delete").click(function(){question=window.confirm("Are you sure?");)
if (question){
    //Submit the form here
}
else{
    alert("Not deleted!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it too complex, you can do something as simple as:

```
<form >
  <input name="foo" value="foo">

  <button name="sub0" value="sub0" onclick="
    return window.confirm('sure?');
  ">submit 0</button>

  <button name="sub1" value="sub1" onclick="
    return window.confirm('sure?');
  ">submit 1</button>

</form>
```

If the user clicks OK on the confirm dialog, the form submits from whichever button was pressed. If not, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

My 2c:

```
... (edited: removed the value parameter. buttons don't need that)
<button onclick='deleteFoo(); ' >Delete Foo</button>
<button onclick='deleteBar(); ' >Delete Bar</button>
<button onclick='allowEdit(); ' >Edit</button>   
...

function deleteFoo() {
    do-your-modal-whichever-way-you-want;
    if confirmed, 
         $('#form-id').attr('action','your-action-for-delete-foo');
         $('#form-id').submit();
    else-just-return
}


function deleteBar() {
    do-your-modal-whichever-way-you-want;
    if confirmed, 
         $('#form-id').attr('action','your-action-for-delete-bar');
         $('#form-id').submit();
    else-just-return
}


function allowEdit() {
    whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting closer. For `$('#form-id').attr('action','your-action-for-delete-foo');`, what is the value for `your-action-for-delete-foo`?

Comment: Your action html page. Usually a <form method='post' action='/dothis.htm'>. As you said, you will process the form according to the clicked button so, I assume you have a different action depending upon the button clicked (an up vote would help me if you like the initial answer. TIA).

Comment: That's not correct, it's a single action for both buttons. In my original question I stated it's the same form with multiple submit buttons.

Comment: So? Just do the rest of the thinking! Having the functions for each button allow you to do the necessary processing ..... and, then, submit(). In your case, specifically, go ahead and have the action=',......' in the form tag. Just do the submit() in the functions for each button.